# Sinonjs how to stub dependency injection class?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I have sample code written below (which simplifies from my actual code implementation), the main idea of this simplified version, is to understand how can I stub the class for unit testing

I have `Sensor` class which is dependency injected into `Context` class, this `Sensor` will obtain data from some `IO` port.

The sensor data will be compared at `ComputeSensor` class for an expected value, and it will insert `report` key into the `context.report` object.

May I know how can I stub or mock the `Sensor` class, so I could create a fake value to test the code?

```
class Sensor {
  getData() {        
    return {
      heat: this.getHeatSensor(), // get data from some IO
      speed: this.getSpeedSensor() // get data from some IO
    }
  }
}

class Context {
  constructor(sensor) {
    this.report = {};
    this.sensor = sensor;
    this.computeSensor = new ComputeSensor();
  }

  execute() {
    this.computeSensor.compute(this, this.sensor.getData());
  }
}

class ComputeSensor {
  compute(context, sensorData) {
    if (sensorData.heat === 123
      && sensorData.speed === 321) 
    {
      context.report = {
        sensor: 'ok'
      }  
    }
  }
}

const sensor = new Sensor();
const context = new Context(sensor);
context.execute();
console.log(context.report) // { sensor: 'ok }
```

Maybe desired stub code will be like this?

```
const stubSensor = sinon.createStubInstance(Sensor);
// Inject the stub return value here?
stubSensor.getData() = {
  heat: 123,
  speed: 321,
}
```

Or I could write a mock class as below..But I think Sinon could do that..

```
class MockSensor {
      getData() {
             return {
                   heat: 123,
                   speed: 321
             }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly.
You can stub the methods, so when there is a IO call a fixed value will be returned. 
e.g.

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

class Sensor {
    getHeatSensor(){

    }
    getSpeedSensor(){

    }
    getData() {
        return {
            heat: this.getHeatSensor(), // get data from some IO
            speed: this.getSpeedSensor() // get data from some IO
        }
    }
}

class Context {
    constructor(sensor) {
        this.report = {};
        this.sensor = sensor;
        this.computeSensor = new ComputeSensor();
    }

    execute() {
        this.computeSensor.compute(this, this.sensor.getData());
    }
}

class ComputeSensor {
    compute(context, sensorData) {
        if (sensorData.heat === 123 && sensorData.speed === 321) {
            context.report = {
                sensor: 'ok'
            }
        }
    }
}

describe('Test Sensor', () => {
    it('should compute value ', () => {
        const sensor = new Sensor;
        sinon.stub(sensor,'getHeatSensor').returns(123);
        sinon.stub(sensor,'getSpeedSensor').returns(321);

        const context = new Context(sensor);
        context.execute();

        console.log(context.report);

        expect(context.report).to.deep.equal({sensor:'ok'})
        sensor.getHeatSensor.restore(); //don't forget to restore
        sensor.getSpeedSensor.restore();
    });

    it('should return empty object ', () => {
        const sensor = new Sensor;
        sinon.stub(sensor,'getHeatSensor').returns(99);
        sinon.stub(sensor,'getSpeedSensor').returns(84);

        const context = new Context(sensor);
        context.execute();

        console.log(context.report);

        expect(context.report).to.deep.equal({})
        sensor.getHeatSensor.restore();
        sensor.getSpeedSensor.restore();
    });

});
```

Hope this help, to clarify.

Comment: how can i stub the method, if use sinon.createStubInstance?